# lower case string in c

Tags: c, string, lowercase

**i had a few line here :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *tolower(char *data)
{
    char *p = data;
    while(*p)
    {
        printf("nilai p : %c\n",*p);
            if(*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z')
            {
                *p += ('a' - 'A');
            }
        p++;
    }
    return p;

}

int main()
{

    char *a = "HajAR BleH";
    char *b = tolower(a);

    printf("nilai b : %s\n",b);
    printf("nilai a - A : %d\n",'a' - 'A');
return 0;
}
```

**next, compiled, running on gdb, and segmentation traced**

```
xxx@aaa:/tmp$ gcc -o aa aa.c --debug
xxx@aaa:/tmp$ gdb -q aa
Reading symbols from /tmp/aa...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/aa 
nilai p : H

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804841e in tolower (data=0x804855e "HajAR BleH") at aa.c:11
11                  *p += ('a' - 'A');
(gdb)
```

**question**

**1.** i think `*p += ('a' - 'A');` will equal as `'H' += ('a' - 'A')` and equal with `72 += 32`
but, accidentally segmentation fault, how come it could be ?

**2.** why need to add ('a' - 'A') to make `char`/`byte` get lower ?

thats all for now, thank in advance

Comment: 'a' - 'A' doesn't make sense unless you were familiar with the ASCII table.  The numeric difference between 'a' and 'A' is what you have to add to an uppercase letter in order to have the equivalent letter in lowercase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to modify a string literal. Change:

```
char *a = "HajAR BleH";
```

to:

```
char a[] = "HajAR BleH";
```

Also, there already is a standard library function called tolower(), which you should in fact be using in your code. Call your own function something else.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely cause of the `SEGV` is that the compiler has placed `a` in read-only memory, as it is allowed to do with string literals.

Try changing `a`'s definition to:

```
char a[] = "HajAR BleH";
```

As a matter of style, there already exists a standard function called `tolower`, which does something different (convert *one character* to lowercase). With this in mind, I'd suggest:

1. giving your function a different name to avoid confusion;
2. using `tolower` in your implementation to convert one character to lowercase.

Comment: even i dont really care whether there is or isnt any function tolower() exist , thank for remind me though

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the seg-fault is you are trying to modify a string literal which is resides in read only memory leading to undefined behavior.

Try changing

```
char *a = "HajAR BleH";
```

to

```
char a[] = "HajAR BleH";
```

Comment: Actually it is `s/char \[\]a/char a\[\]/` ;) `[]` are char class.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the problem with the read-only memory, you need to return `data` rather than `p`. By the time your loop has finished, `p` points to the null-terminator.

Answer (score 0):

1: Essentially your code is correct, however you're trying to modify a constant string (`char *a` should reda `const char *a`). You'll have to create another character array you'll be able to modify.

2: `('a' - 'A')` calculates the "difference" in the ascii values between lower case characters and upper case characters (32).